# Find the index of maximum values in a window size of each rows of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df and df1. I want to find the maximum in `each 4 columns` and each rows in df  and then the value of that column in `df1`.

```
        import pandas as pd

        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['a'] = [ 1, 2]
        df['b'] = [ 2, 20]
        df['c'] = [ 4, 2]
        df['d'] = [ 6, 2]
        df['e'] = [ 10, 2]
        df['f'] = [ 3, 2]
        df['g'] = [ 5, 22]
        df['h'] = [ 1, 2]
        df
           a    b   c   d   e   f   g   h
        0   1   2   4   6   10  3   5   1
        1   2   20  2   2   2   2   22  2

        df1 = pd.DataFrame()
        df1['a'] = [ 1, 2]
        df1['b'] = [ 2, 2]
        df1['c'] = [ 4, 12]
        df1['d'] = [ 1, 2]
        df1['e'] = [ -5, 2]
        df1['f'] = [ 3, 32]
        df1['g'] = [ 15, -1]
        df1['h'] = [ 1, 2]

               a    b   c   d   e   f   g   h
            0   1   2   4   1   -5  3   15  1
            1   2   2   12  2   2   32  -1  2
```

For example, in the following: for the first row, the maximum of the column `(a, b,c,d)` is 6 which is in column `d`. And the value of df1 in column d is 1. Or, for column `(e,f,g,h)` the maximum is 15 which is in `e`. and the values for the column `e` in df1 is -5. So the final output is like the out.

Out:

```
           a1   b1
        0   1   -5
        1   2   -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to get the column name of max value in each 4 columns then pass its row and column name as tuple to index the `df1.stack()`

```py
out = pd.concat([df1.stack()[df[df.columns[i:i+4]].idxmax(axis=1).items()].droplevel(level=-1)
                 for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 4)], axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

   0  1
0  1 -5
1  2 -1
```